# modifiy multiple react components on trigger

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have input forms which I use on several places on my single-page website.
There is a single react-component *class* named `Subscribe` which contains the whole `<form>` allowing the user to enter a email and subscribe to my newsletter.

When the user submits subscribes in any `<Subscribe>`, I want to change the content of every occurence of `<Subscribe>` on the page. Its very easy for the single `<Subscribe>` the user actually used, however I can not find a suitable way to modifiy the state of the other `<Subscribe>` components. Currently I'm, using plain Javascript to modifiy the DOM-nodes.

Is there a way to do this directly in React?

Comment: You could have a central store for the data and each component subscribes to that store for changes. Check out the flux architecture: https://facebook.github.io/flux/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this is probably better done with **Flux** as a comment said in your post.
You should store the changes and manipulate that storage data with a service.

You can check https://facebook.github.io/flux/ for further information.

But, if you're rendering the page with React as well you can probably set a state for that page and then pass this one as a prop in each `<Subscribe>` component. You should manipulate this submission in the same page or through a mixin but not let the component do the job to get the state changed as well.

In your page:

```
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        alreadySubscribed: false
    };
}
```

When the user hit the Subscribe button: `this.setState({alreadySubscribed: true});`

When you render each `<Subscribe>` component pass a prop, for example: `disableSubscribe={this.state.alreadySubscribe}`

Comment: Okay, I hope I will have time for looking into Flex anytime soon... Meanwhile, OK I understand your concept, but how do I access `this` (= page) from within the click-handler which is placed in `<Subscribe>`. Or otherwise put, how can I handle the click not in `<Subscribe>` but in the parent component?

Comment: Ah I think I found a solution: Just found out that you can pass functions as props...